# Photon OSでIPv4をDHCPで設定するには

Tags: linux, vmware, systemd

#### 環境:

Windows 10 の Vmware Player上でPhoton OSを使っています。

#### 問題点：

ネットワーク設定ファイルの `[Network]` セクションに `DHCP=yes` の設定を記載しているが、`ip a` コマンドの結果の `2:eth0` の中にはinetの記載がないこと。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デフォルトで DHCP 自体は有効なようです。

[Turning Off DHCP | Photon OS Documentation](https://vmware.github.io/photon/docs-v5/administration-guide/managing-network-configuration/turning-off-dhcp/)

以下の記述も参考にしてみてください。

[systemd-networkd | IPv6 - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/IPv6#systemd-networkd_3)

> networkd ではインターフェイスごとに IPv6 を無効化できます。ネットワークユニットの `[Network]` セクションに `LinkLocalAddressing=ipv4` または `LinkLocalAddressing=no` が指定されている場合、networkd はマッチするインターフェイスで IPv6 を設定しません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
/etc/systemd/networkd/配下には99.dhcp-en.network ファイルしか存在しておらず、そのファイル内の[Network]セッションにLocalAddressing=ipv4を記載してみました。#systemctl restart systemd-networkd 実施後#ip a　で上記写真の2:eth0を確認した所、IPV4（inet）の記載はなく、今だinet6が記載されたままでした。

IPv4がeth0に追加できない原因として考えられるものは他にあればご教授いただければと思います。

Comment: VMware player の設定変更を行った結果無事IPv4をDHCPサーバが行ってくれました。

Comment: 解決した場合には、コメント欄で終わらせずにぜひ個別の回答として投稿してください。

Answer (score 2):

VMware player の設定変更を行った結果無事IPv4をDHCPサーバが行ってくれました。
＊設定変更した後DHCPがIPv4を自動で割り当ててくれるようになりました。